# Send data between pages using $_POST and $_SESSION

Tags: php, session, post

Hey I'm trying to send the data that I have in an input saving it in a $_SESSION variable, but when I get redirected to the page I get and  **Undefined index: idEmployee**. Here is my approach.

**The code of the first page**

```
session_start();

include('../includes/config.php');
include('../includes/db.php');

if (isset($_POST['updateEmployee'])) {
    if (isset($_POST['tempId'])) {
        $myVar = $_POST['tempId'];    
        $_SESSION['idEmployee'] = $myVar;
        header("Location:nuevoCliente.php");  
    }
}
?>

<?php

$query = "SELECT employee.employee_id, employee.employee_name, employee.employee_cc, type_employee.t_Employee_name FROM employee, type_employee WHERE employee.t_Employee_id = type_employee.t_Employee_id";

global $db;

$result = $db->query($query); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){   
  echo "<tr><td style='text-align:center'>" . 
  $row['employee_name'] . "</td><td style='text-align:center'>" . 
  $row['employee_cc'] . "</td><td style='text-align:center'> " . 
  $row['t_Employee_name'] . "</td>" .
  "<td style='text-align:center; vertical-align:inherit'>" . 
  "<form style='margin-bottom: initial;' method='post'     action='nuevoCliente.php'>" . 
  "<input type='hidden' name='tempId' value='" . $row['employee_id'] . "'/>";
 echo $row['employee_id'] ;
 echo "<input class='btn btn-primary btn-block'  name='updateEmployee'    type='submit' value='Modificar'/></form></td></tr>";  
 }

 echo "</table></div>";
 ?>
```

**Code of the Second Page**

```
<?php

session_start();

include('../includes/config.php');
include('../includes/db.php');

echo $_SESSION['idEmployee'];

?>
```

What am I doing wrong?. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The **Undefined index: idEmployee** is solved. Using the var_dump($_SESSION), I realizes that ['idEmployee'] didn't exist, so I just changed with a echo $_SESSION['tempId'] and the problem is already gone.

**Code of the Second Page**

```
<?php

session_start();

include('../includes/config.php');
include('../includes/db.php');

echo $_SESSION['tempId'];

?>
```

Now the error is that the 'tempId' variable is always the same no matters what employee I choose in the table. Any ideas?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sounds ok to me. Try running `var_dump($_SESSION)` on your second page.

Comment: Your code seems ok. Check if you don't overwrite this variable, or do any session_destroy in another file that you include.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes Thanks for the answer. I just run var_dump($_SESSION) and I another bad stuff is happening. The ["tempId"] variable indeed, has a value but is a wrong value, the value is always the same no matter what employee I have chosen in the fisrt page. Do you know why?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte I don't overwrite the variable. I just use a session_destroy() in a logout.php, but I am call that page. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Try putting a `session_write_close()` just before the redirect.

Comment: @BramGerritsen Thanks for your answer but the value of ['tempId'] is always the same no matter what.